# Windows phone emulator for web testing

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, mobile-website, windows-phone-8-emulator, web-testing

I've installed win phone SDK with emulator included. I've trying to lunch the emulator for website testing without running VS.

My VS 2012 is updated(which was required as I know), VTx is enabled properly as well. When I try to run CMD on **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\8.0** and enter this to CMD: **xde -vhd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Micros
oft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Emulation\Images\Flash.vhd"**

I get this window:

[image]
Tried to click both options, in "Get help" option I don't receive anything and if try to click "run the program without getting help" I can see something loading, but nothing loads and it does not open any windows/emulators and it's like nothing has happened.

Any help would be so much appreciated. Thank you in forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the search for the answers I came across with a solution to just simply open VS and click to install it through this environment. This solved all the issues I had and now it is up and running.